# How do I make LCM works with floating numbers?

Tags: python, math, floating-point, calculator, lcm

Newbie to python...

Currently I'm writing a code for physics calculator, mirror especially, the formula of the mirror is **1/s + 1/s' = 1/f**.

Example, I want to input the number to the **s'** is 3 and the **f** is 1.2

> 1/s + 1/3 = 1/1.2

...and now I wanted the **LCM** between them to be known but since **LCM** in python can't work with float numbers, only integer. So, how do I make math.lcm works with float numbers?

I use python 3.9.13

Comment: So you want to solve for `s`, given `s'` and `f`? Just do the algebra.

Comment: This is not an LCM problem.  This is an algebra problem.  The answer is `1 / (1/f - 1/s')`.  In your example, s=`2`.

Comment: The very [definition of LCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) describes it in terms of integers, so it's unclear what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need to calculate the LCM but something like this would work:

```py
import math

def lcm_float(a, b, precision):
    a = round(a, precision)
    b = round(b, precision)
    return math.lcm(int(a*10**precision), int(b*10**precision))/10**precision
```

It's basically converting the floats to integers, calculating the LCM, and going back to floats.
The precision is how many decimal places you will be considering.